# In English, what is a 'being', and what things cannot be called 'beings'?

Tags: meaning

Maybe this a philosophy question. But this is also an English question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Usually, this refers to living things--even hypothetical, alien life forms. Depending on usage, it may or may not include plants.

Answer (score 2):

I agree with Jay, but would also add that in the realm of philosophy, something has "being" if it exists. Of course, this opens an existential can of worms.

"Being" could be seen as the gerund form for the verb "to be", which means "to exist".

Answer (score 0):

A sentient life form, capable of planning. Homo sapiens. Aliens, if they exist and can plan their lives.

This excludes all animals and everything further down the food chain.

Just to clarify, I don't consider a gorilla to be a 'being', even if it appears to communicate with sign language.

Comment: Adding *sentient* qualifies *being* in the way you describe, but without *sentient*, I believe it most often includes "animals and everything further down the food chain."

Comment: @jay My gorilla plans things? A rat plans things? A snail plans things? Where do you draw the line?

Comment: Again, you're talking about *sentient* beings, which is a small class among all beings.

Comment: @jay Perhaps I wasn't clear. If we remove sentient, we're left with "life form, capable of planning". What I was trying to say is that you'd have to remove "planning" as well, which leaves us with "life form". A snail is a life form, so a snail is a being?

Comment: I say "yes" to the snail; planning is not required. Here is a reference that I think supports this: "a living thing that has (or can develop) the ability to act or function independently" (http://wordnetweb.princeton.edu/perl/webwn?s=being).

Comment: @jay Oh well, one man's synset is another man's hyponym I suppose >;-) To me, "being" is more of a http://wordnetweb.princeton.edu/perl/webwn?o2=&o0=1&o7=&o5=&o1=1&o6=&o4=&o3=&s=person&i=0&h=000#c

Answer (score -3):

There seem to be quite a number of humans who are not “beings” – they can’t think or plan – more like parasites, and also quite a number of animals which have more “being” than some humans: they can think and figure things out. Intelligence makes the being; ”awareness” makes the being; an “aha” moment makes a being, in my personal opinion.